# I want to change the textButton in asp from my Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a little situations.
I have one button who needs to change when one flag from my database have some value.
I can make it simple, but I need to make it from Resources because when the user change language, the text needs to change on proper language.

.ascx code:

```
<div class="" style="text-align: right; margin-top: 5px; padding-top: 5px; text-align: right;">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Save %>" OnClick="OnSaveClick" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

.cs code :

```
 Customer c = new Customer().GetById(Convert.ToInt32(curentId));

        if (c.Image == null)
            imgProd.ImageUrl = "/styles/img/defaultProduct.jpg";
        else
        {
            string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(c.Image);
            imgProd.ImageUrl = "data:Image/jpg;base64, " + strBase64;
        }
        if (c.Lead == 1)
        {
            btnSave.Text = "Save as Partner";
        }
```

I want to make something like this:

```
btnSave.Text = Resources:Resource, SaveasPartner;
```

I hope I made myself clear abouth what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: Asp.net has a ready-to-use i18n solution, pls follow [this] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms227427(v=vs.100)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and it works for me:

```
 if (c.Lead)
            {
                btnSave.Text = Resources.Resource.saveaspartner;
            }
```